# property list from object of type id

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to get property list from object of type `id` using `class_copyPropertyList`.

```
properties = class_copyPropertyList([WSAT_SignIN class], &count);
```

Instead of model class name, I have an `id` of type `WSAT_SignIN`. Beside the  `class_copyPropertyList` method, is there a way to get property from an id?

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
 objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([WSAT_SignIN class], &count);
  for (int i = 0; i < [YourArray count]; i++)
   {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
     NSLog(@" prorerty name %@", strName);
  }
```

Comment: in this i dont know  my classname only know object  of type id . id containWSAT_SignIN, using id how get my class property

Comment: You are getting properties from this objc_property_t *properties WSAT_SignIN is  your class

Comment: instead of  WSAT_SignIN  i know object of type  id .[id contain WSAT_SignIN class] using id how to get properties

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer,

```
   Class classname=id;

  properties = class_copyPropertyList([classname class], &count);
```

without using classname i got the property list